# Can't POST credentials on OCN client

Tags: shareandcharge

I have a problem with OCN-client.

When I call POST http://host/ocpi/2.2/credentials, response:

```
Role with party_id=ABC and country_code=ES not listed in (truncated)...
```

Means that I have to register our company?
How I can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the client will not accept the credentials handshake if you are not already listed in the registry. Running the registry locally will create a new network only existing on your local development environment. To do this, you would also need to point the OCN client to your local network in its configuration. This is good during development, though there will be no other MSPs/CPOs to interact with out of the box (see https://bitbucket.org/shareandcharge/ocn-tools for how you could do that yourself). Once you are ready, you could then access our public test environment via your local OCN client (the default configuration values point to it), or connect to one remotely.